# integrating glassfy for the chinese app store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

Are there any special steps needed when using glassfy for managing my in-app subscriptions & purchases for the Chinese App Store? Do they offer a chinese server connection in their API reference?

Or do I need to use my own subscription management-servers which need to reside in china, due to the [new regulation](https://www.businessofapps.com/news/hurdles-for-app-developers-apple-enforces-chinese-licensing-on-app-store/)?

I would like to unify the management for android & ios. Does glassfy or revenuecat or any similar service offer a specific method to ask from chinese servers?

I could not find the mobile app development stack exchange, that's why I asked here. I think this would be helpful for a lot of people, to know this information, and to easily find it on stackoverflow. Since I cannot think of any other place to ask this, where people would easily find it/search for it.